# Issue with CSS transform property - Can't adjust background color

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a box with the text on left with rotate from top to bottom but can't handle the width of the background, background color is showing additional but when I reduce the width, height is also getting reduced, here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/a3y95eq9/) for the code I have created.

Text should also start from top width should not be showing extra.

`HTML` Code is

```
<div class="box">
  <span>Vertical Text</span>
</div>
```

And the `CSS` is

```
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  min-height: 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box > span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  width: 150px;
  min-height: 150px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: arial;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Result I am looking is as attached below

[image]

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. What's the desired result?

Comment: @Marcos I just updated what I am looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a3y95eq9/6/)
`box-sizing: border-box;` was the reason for the overflow

`text-aling: right;` will set text to top

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.box > div {
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  width: 20px;
  min-height: 150px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: arial;
  transform: rotate();
}

.box > div > p {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: seems to be okay but how about the width of span, that extra width shouldn't not be there, Actually I wanted to keep that span width minimal, as width is from left, same from right.

Comment: pls check the updated question with the image I've attached is what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

You are facing such problem because of `border: 2px solid #444` property, as it takes up 2px from 150px of total width in drawing the border of the div. So the actual area width for the `<span>` would be `150px - (2px + 2px) = 146px` (2px of border on either side)

If you set

```
.box > span 
{
    text-align:right; 
    width: 146px;
    min-height: 146px;
}
```

It would resolve the issue.

Comment: I would recommend deleting  `.box {box-sizing: border-box;}` . If you delete box-sizing you don't need to play with width/height.

Comment: Agreed, but in case if div cannot extend beyond 150px due to UI limitations, then this solution can be applied.

Comment: @RajatPatel please see my updated question, the image showing what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
.box > span::before{
  content:'';
  position:relative;
  margin-left:70px;
}
```

Comment: @SanjeevK that's how it's going to work or you have to wrap your span text in another div i.e. add one more div.

Comment: @SanjeevK try my updated code. This works without wrapping it into div.